# Is it possible to cast in fast enumeration?

Tags: java

Suppose you start with

```
                         // Set<String>
Object arrayOfSomething[] = someObject.toArray();
```

Now, i know that `arrayOfSomething` is really an `arrayOfStrings`, i'd like to iterate over

Currently, i

```
for (Object o : arrayOfSomething) {
   String strValue = ((String) o).trim();
    ...
```

Is something along the following possible:

```
for (String (String) strValue : arrayOfSomething) {
    ...
```

Is it possible to cast an object as part of a fast enumeration?

Comment: `for (Object o : arrayOfSomething) { String strValue = o.toString();...` you can also use `Arrays.asList()` or alternatively you can List<String> l = Arrays.asList(arrayOfSomething); then `for(String s :l){.....}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a method `Collection.toArray(T[])` returning an array of type T instead of an array of Objects.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not possible. If `someObject` is a `Set<String>`, you could use the `toArray` method to convert to an array of `String` instead:

```
  String [] arrayOfStrings = someObject.toArray(new String[someObject.size()]);
```